# How do I stop Acrobat from treating copied radio button groups as instances of the original instead of separate copies?

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat, forms, acrobat-pro-dc

I'm working on a multi-page form of multiple-choice questions, each with three possible answers. Each group is named "Ch1Q1" and so on - one chapter per page, so essentially page and question. However, having copied groups over, if I try to rename them to fit the next page, they remain linked to the original group. As a result, if I try renaming Ch1Q1 on page three to Ch3Q1, it renames not only that one but also the equivalent group on page one.

I can't find an option to change the paste function from instance to copy, and some of the copies have worked fine with no discernable difference in how they were copied.

Any idea what's causing this problem and how to resolve it without having to create all the groups individually for every page?

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is to treat the pages as (hidden) Template pages, and spawn them when you set up the form. This will create unique field names for the groups.